# jquery detect enter key on dynamically created textbox

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that creates a textbox:

```
$(".vocab-list").append( $('<li style="margin-left: 307px;" class="vocab-word" id="vocab_' + vocabWords[wordId]['id']+ '"><img width="230px" height="230px" src="' + vocabWords[wordId]['imageURL'] + '" /><div><input type="text" spellcheck="false" id="writeWord" autocorrect="off" maxlength="200" style="width: 230px;border: 0;border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C6C6;border-radius: 0;color:#6e572f;font-size:24px;font-weight:500;"></div></li>').hide().fadeIn(600));
```

How Can I detect the enter key? The following didn't work

```
$('#writeWord').bind("enterKey",function(e){
alert("Enter");
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript capture key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756786/javascript-capture-key)

Comment: `writeWord` isn't a standard HTML tag, do you mean `.writeWord`? Couldn't see `.writeWord` element when you created textbox

Comment: I meant #writeWord ... i just need to detect the enter key from a dyanmically created textbox

Comment: You might be interested in "Map [Enter] key to work like [Tab] key" http://stackoverflow.com/a/27545387/1500195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.on` for dynamic HTML - detect a `keyup` event and then detect if the key up was for the enter key:

```
$(".vocab-list").on("keyup", "#writeWord", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        alert("Enter");
    }
});
```