# "event" is deprecated, what should be used instead?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a found code where "event" is used. It works, but I would like to know what should be used instead.

I'm a novice programmer and there are a concepts that I'm missing. in this case, I'm using a code I found in the web, that can be found in the next link:
https://codepen.io/galulex/pen/eNZRVq

PhpStorm shows me that "event" on onmousemove="zoom(event)" is deprecated. I have tried erasing it but it does not work that way. I would like to know what should I use instead of event.

```
<figure class="zoom" onmousemove="zoom(event)" style="background-image: url(//res.cloudinary.com/active-bridge/image/upload/slide1.jpg)">
  <img src="//res.cloudinary.com/active-bridge/image/upload/slide1.jpg" />
</figure>
```

```
function zoom(e){
  var zoomer = e.currentTarget;
  e.offsetX ? offsetX = e.offsetX : offsetX = e.touches[0].pageX
  e.offsetY ? offsetY = e.offsetY : offsetX = e.touches[0].pageX
  x = offsetX/zoomer.offsetWidth*100
  y = offsetY/zoomer.offsetHeight*100
  zoomer.style.backgroundPosition = x + '% ' + y + '%';
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using inline JS anymore: use `element.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {...});` instead.

Comment: Use alternative jquery options for do same

Comment: @PriyankMotivaras jQuery is not always the answer.

Comment: @PriyankMotivaras You can also do it with the excellent [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) framework.

Comment: @Andreas But jQuery can solve small things for new Developers,it's time saving

Comment: Yes @Amn Vanila JS Frameworks is good and faster than jquery with new syntax,but jquery is easy to understand for new developers

Comment: @amn +1 for Vanilla JS **framework** :)

Comment: @PriyankMotivaras Suggesting to learn jQuery before vanilla JS has always been bad advice; in 2021 it's even very bad advice, and it has been like that in 2019 already.

Comment: @Terry why? Some reasons given here: https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/3kamqn/why_is_inline_onclickfunction_considered_such_a/

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `event` property of the global object (typically `window` in the Web browser) was originally added by Microsoft in Internet Explorer. As it often happens, it then gradually found its way into other popular Web browsers and became another de-facto "standard" without being formally specified by W3C or similar authority at the time.

Eventually, [WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org) specified it retroactively in the name of backwards compatibility, defining it as [the "current" event](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-window-event), with an attached cautionary note:

> Web developers are strongly encouraged to instead rely on the [Event](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#event) object passed to event listeners, as that will result in more portable code. This attribute is not available in workers or worklets, and is inaccurate for events dispatched in [shadow trees](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-shadow-tree).

So, the idiomatic solution to the broad class of problems your use case belongs to, is to attach an event listener on the element or its ancestor, typically with the [`addEventListener`](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-eventtarget-addeventlistener) function, and be using the event object that is explicitly passed to the listener.

In your particular case, assuming `figure` below refers to your, well, `figure` element, the event listener (`zoom`) may be attached thus:

```js
figure.addEventListener("mousemove", zoom);
```

Since your `zoom` function already assumes the single argument it is passed is the mouse move event, it will continue working as an event listener without needing changes -- it will be called with the event of interest passed as sole argument every time the mouse moves.

Comment: Be careful with events like `mousemove` - you need to throttle them since they can fire repeatedly at very high intervals. https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf

Comment: @amn I put this line on a document.ready function but the picture just doesn't move once it is zoomed it.

Comment: @max UIEvents ([mousemove](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-mousemove) included) are now to be fired at "optimal frequency rate to balance responsiveness with performance" (understand in painting frames only), i.e they are already debounced.

Comment: @Germán Please explain better -- you did not ask how or whether the picture (figure, I assume?) should zoom, you asked what you should use instead of the deprecated `event` global. I answered. Do you think it is the fact that you changed from using the deprecated global to event listeners as described in my answer, that introduced the "picture doesn't move once it is zoomed" problem? Or was that problem there from the beginning? Edit your question to better reflect what you want, please.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking for the reason behind, so your answer is totally valid. Sorry for not checking before.

Comment: If the `zoom` function has multiple parameters, how would the arguments be passed?

Comment: The event listener is always called with a single argument that is the event. No other arguments are passed. You'll have to pass them yourself like `addEventListener("mousemove", ev => zoom(ev, "foobar", { x: 1 }))` where `"foobar"` and `{ x: 1 }` are examples of additional arguments. You can also use `Function.prototype.bind` to similar effect, although for readability and because `bind` doesn't really let you well, *bind* parameters in arbitrary order (only from left to right, and you have to specify the value that will bind `this`), I prefer to just use arrow functions, as illustrated.

Answer (score 31):

I was getting this error on VS code while using it like this

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function()
{
     console.log(event); 
});
```

***The warning got solved using the below code***

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event)
{
     console.log(event); 
});
```

**Reason- It's missing the event parameter in the event handler function. It ends up using the global window.event which is fragile and is deprecated**.

Answer (score 15):

You can do this too (in react),

```
<input type="file" onChange={event => handleFileChange(event)} />
```

Comment: Also works in Svelte

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem.  I found this [code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) worked for me like event used to.

```
function hide(e){
  e.currentTarget.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
  // When this function is used as an event handler: this === e.currentTarget
}

var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for(var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++){    
  // Console: print the clicked <p> element 
  ps[i].addEventListener('click', hide, false);
}
// Console: print <body>
document.body.addEventListener('click', hide, false);

// Click around and make paragraphs disappear
```