# Create and dispatch events javascript. Code execution simple delegation

Tags: javascript, events, delegates

Comming from a c# background, I just want to create an event in a certain point of my code, soas to be dispatched elsewere, meaning that if in some part of the code there has been a subscription, this delegate function is called.

So I tried to do:

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log("delegated call achieved!");
}

const myEvent = new Event('onMyConditionIsMet', myFunction, false);  

//at this point the program the subscription takes place
function whatever1() { 
    //...not meaningfull code
    myEvent.addEventListener('onMyConditionIsMet');
    //myEvent += myFunction; c# way subscription in case it makes sense 
}  

//at this point in the program, event subscription is checked and  
//delegate func run in case there has been a subscription
function whatever2() { 
    //...not meaningfull code
    myEvent?.invoke(); // ?.invoke(); would be the c# way to do it. 
}
```

All the examples I found are related to DOM events, but my case would be for events I create myself, think these are called synthetic events.
Another assumption I make in this question is that there would be no arguments in the delegate call function, so, just to be clear with the naming, it would be a delegate with no arguments. Just pointing this because in c# events are just delegate funcs with no arguments, so a specific type of delegate. Not sure if this works the same way in Javscript.

What would be the approach to do this? (Meaning creating a simple event instance, subscribing, and executing the delegated code if there is any subscription)?

Comment: Look for [Document.createEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent), the example is quite clear.

Comment: thanks for your comment, checked that. What is `elem` in the documentation? in the `elem.addEventListener('build', function (e) {
  // e.target matches elem
}, false);`

Comment: The DOM element on which to apply it.

Comment: there is no dom element in my case, that is where my confusion is comming from

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette `Document.createEvent` is deprecated and should not be recommended. When using events on HTML nodes the event constructor should be used like OP already is applying. The question is about creating an Event based structure that doesn't involve HTML nodes.

Comment: if the problem is in node.js where there is no dom, or the event is not related to any DOM element, what is the way to create the event, subscribe and delegate the execution of the code?. That is the point of my question

Comment: in my case I am in the browser so I would be able to use the DOM in case of need. However for my concrete example, the event and the code I need to handle have no relation to any DOM element. Along with this then I wonder how this woud be done when the DOM is not available, which might not be :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the functionality you are looking for can be best obtained by using OOP/Classes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#prototype_methods

Edit: see this also - ["event" is deprecated, what should be used instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58341832/event-is-deprecated-what-should-be-used-instead)