# JSX: 'event' is deprecated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
onSelectedShowdateChangeHandler() {
  this.setState(
    { selectedShowdate: event.target.value },
    this.getShowtimeList
  );
}
```

Hi guys, I'm having a `"event" is deprecated` error here, not so sure what I should replace it with. Thank you so much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58341832/event-is-deprecated-what-should-be-used-instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handler callbacks will be given an `event` object as an argument when invoked. Just add that argument to your function:

```js
onSelectedShowdateChangeHandler(event) {
    // Function body
}
```

It's up to you, but some prefer to just name it `e` or similar to avoid clashing with the "global" `event` object.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
onSelectedShowdateChangeHandler(myEvent) {
  this.setState(
    { selectedShowdate: myEvent.target.value },
    this.getShowtimeList
 );
}
```

I'm surprised you're still using it, unless you're using legacy code. `event` was deprecated years ago.

Comment: Ohh, what does "deprecated" mean tho? Sorry for the stupid questions I'm actually not very familiar with Javascript. But yeap, it is legacy codes from my company, written many many years ago.

Comment: @Jerome https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deprecate