# in react i want to use event for targeting value from textarea tag but this error comes out ( Unexpected use of 'event' )

Tags: reactjs

[image]

i want to use events but this error comes how can i solve this ?

```
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
ERROR in [eslint]
src\componets\TextForm.js
  Line 12:17:  Unexpected use of 'event'  no-restricted-globals

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this by adding the `event` object as a parameter in your function

```
const handleOnChange = (event) => {
  console.log("handleOnChange");
  setText(event.target.value);
}
```

Also its better to check if event is valid before trying to access the target object from it.

Please see : ["event" is deprecated, what should be used instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58341832/event-is-deprecated-what-should-be-used-instead)

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark the question as answered.